# When Undertow server feeds org.xnio.XnioWorker#taskPool?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, undertow, xnio

I am trying to understand how `org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread` works. As I see it is extended by `org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker` and overrides `java.util.concurrent.Executor#execute` which "put" `Runnable` to taskPool. But during debug spring web flux applciation `org.xnio.XnioWorker#execute` does not invoked and looks like this pool is unused. (A `Thread#run with queue polling` is used in internals).

Could somebody tell what is the purpose of `org.xnio.XnioWorker.TaskPool` and under what conditions this pool is fed `Runnable` tasks by `Undertow` server?

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you have blocking IO it is meant to be run on the worker threads. This is done when dispatch is called and there is a helper handler that does it for you [BlockingHandler](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/server/handlers/BlockingHandler.java#L54).

Comment: Do not understand you properly. The problem that `TaskPool` is not populated when Undertow receive requests at least with low loading. Stil not clear when it uses `TaskPool`. And how it determines blocking IO?